# Why in order to read multiple lines of a text with fgets we need to set fgets()!=NULL?

Tags: c

If I would like to read multiple lines from a text with `fgets`, and according to my textbok,  I would do something like this:

```
 char str[53];
 ...
 while(fgets(str, max, f)!=NULL){
   ...
 }
```

If `str` is just a string of n characters of a line, how does the program read the second line? According to a documentation, shouldn't the loop stop when it reaches the end of line?

> **fgets**
>   Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str
>   until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the
>   end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

Comment: You're setting nothing, you're just telling it to stop when it reaches end of file (at which point it returns `NULL`)

Comment: You don't read with `fopen`.  You use `fopen` to create a data structure which you pass to `fgets` to read from the file.  `fgets` reads one line each time it is called.  You are calling it multiple times in a while loop, and it will read one line on each iteration.  When there are no more lines to read, `fgets` returns NULL and the loop terminates.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry, my bad. It was a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> On success, the function returns str.
>   If the end-of-file is encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is set (feof). If this happens before any characters could be read, the pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain unchanged).
>   If a read error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by str may have changed).

str is the buffer you specified as the first argument. If `fgets` is done reading, NULL is returned.

Comment: If we set the first line to let's say, as 30 characters, and the second line as 30 characters, wouldn't the loop stop at the second cycle? Because we defined `str` as `char str[53];`.

Comment: @kevin `fgets()` does NOT append to `str`, with each call you overwrite the previous content.